# SharePoint 2013 how to move promoted links to another site

Tags: sharepoint-server, promoted-links

I do not have access to designer,  I tried content and structure and also saved as template which almost worked URLs didn't carry over.   Any OOB solutions for moving promoted links to another site in the same collection?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

1. Export the Promoted Links list to Excel though List ribbon->Export to Excel.
2. In the Excel, copy the items with the relevant columns, and paste them to another list promoted links list in Quick Edit view.

[image]